# Setting onclicklistener to action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an icon in my actionbar how do i set an onclicklistener to the item i've got so far with this and tried to add and intent but its still not working

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.item3) { 

    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(null, HomeMainActivity.class);
    startActivity(homeIntent);

        return true;    
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the line `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` before the If condition

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.item3) { 

    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(null, HomeMainActivity.class);
    startActivity(homeIntent);

        return true;    
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```